# How can I test `Router NavigationEnd Event` in angular 2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-routing

Does anyone know how can I test `Router NavigationEnd Event`? I have the code below in Angular 2 and I am using Jasmine.

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, Event } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class IhmPageClassService {
    emitPageClass = new EventEmitter<string>();
    currentRoute: string;

    constructor(router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                this.currentRoute = (<NavigationEnd>event).url;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

So I've had some luck testing this using Subjects.

In your test setup you create a eventsSubject.

`let eventsSub = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);`

Then create your routerStub:

`routerStub = {
  events: eventsSub
}`

Then create the NavigationEnd object.

```
let homeNav = new NavigationEnd(1, 'home', 'home');
```

Using the routerStub now as the value for the `Router` Service in your tests you should now be able to test your function.

```
it('should set the currentRoute correctly', () => {
  eventSub.next(homeNav);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.currentRoute).toEqual('home')      
});
```

Comment: That's correct, you have to provide your own stub/mock to be able to control what is emitted on the router.events observable.  Also, don't forget you have to provide the mock/stub in the TestModule definition: 
`providers: [ { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub } ]`

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901047/angular-6-how-to-mock-router-events-url-response-in-unit-test

Comment: I have these scenarios where I test navigation AND router.events. The problem is that I can't solve both kind of scenarios. Using the Stub trick, then I can test router.events, but all Router.navigate(..) based test fails.

Comment: I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined" because of the provider.  Other searches say that is true since I am using RouterTestingModule.  But if I remove that module then I get "can't find routerLink" errors.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure why would you need to test router events, but if you want to debug them, enable the tracing option like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })
```

This will print the info about the router events on the browser's console:
[image]

Comment: Because I have more code after I get Router Event and I need to test it. I mean, I need the code coverage.