# Angular 6 - how to mock router.events url response in unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

As the title indicates, I need to mock `router.events` in a unit test.

In my component, I doing some regex to grab the first instance of text between slashes in the url; e.g., `/pdp/`

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  }

this.router.events.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(route => {
        if (route instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // debugger
          this.projectType = route.url.match(/[a-z-]+/)[0];
        }
      });
```

My unit tests error out when the component is being built: `Cannot read property '0' of null`.  When I comment-in the debugger, `route` does not seem to be set correctly, yet I am setting it in the unit test itself.  I have done it several different ways (inspired by this post: [Mocking router.events.subscribe() Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475342/mocking-router-events-subscribe-angular2/43284364) and others).

First attempt:

```
providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useValue: {
            events: of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/pdp/project-details/4/edit', 'pdp/project-details/4/edit'))
          }
        },
        // ActivatedRoute also being mocked
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            snapshot: { url: [{ path: 'new' }, { path: 'edit' }] },
            parent: {
              parent: {
                snapshot: {
                  url: [
                    { path: 'pdp' }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
]
```

Second attempt (based on the above post):

```
class MockRouter {
  public events = of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/pdp/project-details/4/edit', '/pdp/project-details/4/edit'))
}

providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: MockRouter
        }
]
```

Third attempt (also based on above post):

```
class MockRouter {
  public ne = new NavigationEnd(0, '/pdp/project-details/4/edit', '/pdp/project-details/4/edit');
  public events = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(this.ne);
    observer.complete();
  });
}

providers: [
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: MockRouter
        }
]
```

Fourth attempt:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn((<any>component).router, 'events').and.returnValue(of(new NavigationEnd(0, '/pdp/project-details/4/edit', 'pdp/project-details/4/edit')))
...
```

Fifth attempt:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(TestBed.get(Router), 'events').and.returnValue(of({ url:'/pdp/project-details/4/edit' }))
...
```

In all the above cases, `route` is not being set; the `NavigationEnd` object is equal to:

```
{ id: 1, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/" }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 32):

It can be as simple as:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule]
}).compileComponents()
    
...
    
const event = new NavigationEnd(42, '/', '/');
(TestBed.inject(Router).events as Subject<Event>).next(event);
```

Comment: TS2339 Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<event>'

Comment: @RichardCollette: You get this as a lining error or an actual error while executing the test? Which Angular version are you running? (in case of a liniting error, this can be ignored (cast to `any`)

Comment: This is a typescript compiler error, not a linting error.  While the returned type of Router.events may implement both Observer and Observable interfaces, the public interface of the events property is Observable which doesn't expose next().  There is a risk of a breaking change in the future if the object returned in the future is not an Observer.   Using Angular 7, TS 3.2.4

Comment: @RichardCollette you are right about the risk of breaking changes in the future. Regarding the compile error: This I cannot understand - the `TestBed.get` method has return type `any`, hence there cannot be any compile time checks (unless you specifically cast the result to `Router`)..

Comment: In my Case, the subscribption in the component does get trigger by this piece of code, but, my test doesn't wait for the subscription to resolve, fixture.whenStable never resolves, I tried everything with async, fakeAsync etc ...

Answer (score 17):

Here is the answer I came up with.  I think I just didn't extend the first approach (above) far enough:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

providers: [
    {
      provide: Router,
      useValue: {
        url: '/non-pdp/phases/8',
        events: of(new NavigationEnd(0, 'http://localhost:4200/#/non-pdp/phases/8', 'http://localhost:4200/#/non-pdp/phases/8')),
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: But then this router is not able to navigate, so you cannot test The scenario where, navigating to "" should redirect to /home for instance

Answer (score 5):

Thought this might help...have a footer component with routerLinks in the template.  Was getting the root not provided error....had to use a "real" router...but have a spied variable..and point the router.events to my test observable so I can control nav events

```
export type Spied<T> = { [Method in keyof T]: jasmine.Spy };

describe("FooterComponent", () => {
   let component: FooterComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;
   let de: DebugElement;
   const routerEvent$ = new BehaviorSubject<RouterEvent>(null);
   let router: Spied<Router>;

 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [provideMock(SomeService), provideMock(SomeOtherService)],
        declarations: [FooterComponent],
        imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    }).compileComponents();

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    (<any>router).events = routerEvent$.asObservable();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
}));
// component subscribes to router nav event...checking url to hide/show a link
it("should return false for showSomeLink()", () => {
    routerEvent$.next(new NavigationEnd(1, "/someroute", "/"));
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.showSomeLink()).toBeFalsy();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const htmlComponent = de.query(By.css("#someLinkId"));
    expect(htmlComponent).toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: This works, but along with this solution, all my tests based on Router.navigate(...) fail. How can you Have both Router.navigate and router.event.subscribe() tested ?

Answer (score 4):

I saw this alternative and it works with `RouterTestingModule` like @daniel-sc 's answer

```
   const events = new Subject<{}>();
   const router = TestBed.get(Router);
   spyOn(router.events, 'pipe').and.returnValue(events);
   events.next('Result of pipe');
```

Comment: get() is deprecated. From v9.0.0, using inject() is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this could help, this is what I did:

```js
const eventsStub = new BehaviorSubject<Event>(null);
    export class RouterStub {
      events = eventsStub;
    }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [AppComponent],
          imports: [RouterTestingModule],
          providers: [
            { provide: HttpClient, useValue: {} },
            { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub },
            Store,
            CybermetrieCentralizedService,
            TileMenuComponentService,
            HttpErrorService
          ],
          schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        tileMenuService = TestBed.get(TileMenuComponentService);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
      }));
```

and then on the test I did this:

```js
     it('should close the menu when navigation to dashboard ends', async(() => {
        spyOn(tileMenuService.menuOpened, 'next');
        component.checkRouterEvents();
        router.events.next(new NavigationEnd (1, '/', '/'));
        expect(tileMenuService.menuOpened.next).toHaveBeenCalledWith(false);
      }));
```

this to verify that after the navigation to route '/' I execute an expected instruction

Answer (score -1):

- use `ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>` to mock the `router.events`
- export it to a service so that you can test it more independently from the component, and other components may also want to use this service ;)
- use `filter` instead of `instanceof`

## source code

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteEventService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  subscribeToRouterEventUrl(): Observable<string> {
    return this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map((event: RouterEvent) => event.url)
      );
  }
}
```

## test code

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {RouteEventService} from './route-event.service';
import {NavigationEnd, NavigationStart, Router, RouterEvent} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';

describe('RouteEventService', () => {
  let service: RouteEventService;
  let routerEventRelaySubject: ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>;
  let routerMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    routerEventRelaySubject = new ReplaySubject<RouterEvent>(1);
    routerMock = {
      events: routerEventRelaySubject.asObservable()
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: Router, useValue: routerMock}
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(RouteEventService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('subscribeToEventUrl should', () => {
    it('return route equals to mock url on firing NavigationEnd', () => {
      const result: Observable<string> = service.subscribeToRouterEventUrl();
      const url = '/mock';

      result.subscribe((route: string) => {
        expect(route).toEqual(url);
      });

      routerEventRelaySubject.next(new NavigationEnd(1, url, 'redirectUrl'));
    });

    it('return route equals to mock url on firing NavigationStart', () => {
      const result: Observable<string> = service.subscribeToRouterEventUrl();
      const url = '/mock';

      result.subscribe((route: string) => {
        expect(route).toBeNull();
      });

      routerEventRelaySubject.next(new NavigationStart(1, url, 'imperative', null));
    });
  });
});
```