# How to unit test Router events with RouterTestingModule

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a component with this code (in ngOnInit):

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  this.scavenger.collect(),
).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
  this.navigationService.setCurrentPage(event.url);
});
```

I need to unit test it, but no way.

All guides / S.O answers about Router events testing uses MockRouter.
I cannot use MockRouter, because I have `<router-outlet>` in the template.

At the moment, my test look like:

```
it('should set current page with end navigation event', fakeAsync(() => {
  const navigationService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NavigationService);
  spyOn(navigationService, 'setCurrentPage');

  const router = TestBed.get(Router);
  router.events.next(new NavigationEnd(1, 'fake', 'fake'));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  expect(navigationService.setCurrentPage).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fake');
}));
```

The test fails **Expected spy setCurrentPage to have been called with [ 'fake' ] but it was never called.**

In the Angular bug link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20942#issuecomment-350889540 this guy propose to use this method, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578093/11730828 here too.

My "before each":

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatSidenavModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]),
        MatIconModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [DefaultLayoutComponent, HeaderComponent, AsideComponent, FooterComponent],
      providers: [DeviceDetectorService],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DefaultLayoutComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding console.log statements to the function under test or otherwise stepping through it in debug mode? Is it possible the test is failing silently on this.scavenger.collect() if that hasn't been made available in the spec?

Comment: I tried to remove this code `this.scavenger.collect()` yeah, it changes nothing, I'm testing other code with scavenger.collect (it is in all my subscribes) and no problems.

Comment: next I would do a couple console.log in the component under test, then click the debug button on the karma page that comes up. This runs test in a more debuggable version. Clicking on the console.log output brings you to the line of code and then you can step through it. For me sometimes, this has revealed where the issues is.