# Router events not executing in unit test

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test my `router.events`, but the events are not triggering, and I am not sure why. I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55578093/1778465) with no luck.

Here is how I have my test setup:

```js
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule, 
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          { path: Constants.routes.login, component: LoginComponent },
          { path: Constants.routes.admin.admin, component: AdminWelcomeComponent },
          { path: Constants.routes.user.user, component: HomeComponent }
        ])
      ]
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });


  it('should be created', () => {
    component.apps = [{ name: '', url: '/test' }];
    component.ngOnInit();

    const event = new NavigationEnd(42, '/test', '/test');
    (TestBed.inject(Router).events as Subject<Event>).next(event);
  });
});
```

As seen in this screenshot, the subscription is not executed.

[image: missed lines]

Comment: Have you also tried using `component.detectChanges()` after `events.next()` ?

Comment: I have not tried that.

Comment: Do you not need to have this in an async, and so a tick and flush to get the subscription to resolve?

Comment: Are you sure `elementApps` is not an empty array at that point in time and therefore it doesn't execute?

Comment: @AndreiGătej `fixture.detectChanges()` worked, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it works! Is it ok if I add it as an answer?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Yeah. I added it before and after the event and after, not sure if it was the before or after one that worked

Comment: @AliF50 that looks like it's the issue, `elementApps` is a `@ViewChildren()`, and calling `fixture.detectChanges()` before the `.next()` made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to make sure that change detection is run:

```js
/* ... */
fixture.detectChanges();

(TestBed.inject(Router).events as Subject<Event>).next(event);
```

Comment: After testing, the fix was to add it before the `.next()`, as it wasn't finding the elements in the template.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Makes sense. I have updated the answer. Thanks!